# When is 'readable' event actually emitted? stream.Readable

Tags: javascript, node.js, stream, buffer

```
const stream = require('stream')
const readable = new stream.Readable({
    encoding: 'utf8',
    highWaterMark: 16000,
    objectMode: false
})

const news = [
    'News #1',
    'News #2',
    'News #3'
]

readable._read = () => {
    if(news.length) {
        return readable.push(news.shift() + '\n')
    }
    return readable.push(null)
}

readable.on('readable', () => {
    let data = readable.read()
    if(data) {
        process.stdout.write(data)
    }
})

readable.on('end', () => {
    console.log('No more feed')
})
```

Why does this code work? 'readable' is fired when there is some data in the buffer. Why is this working if I am not pushing any data inside in the stream? I read only when '_read' is called. I am not calling it, why is it firing readable event? I am noob at node.js and have just started learning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you read the docs, it clearly mentions `readable._read(size)` **This function MUST NOT be called by application code directly. It should be implemented by child classes, and called by the internal Readable class methods only.**

In you code you've implemented the *internal* `_read`, so when down the code you do `readable.read()`, your implementation is called *internally* and hence the code executes. If you comment out `readable._read = ...` or rename to something else in your code you'll see this error:

`Error [ERR_METHOD_NOT_IMPLEMENTED]: The _read() method is not implemented`

Also again from docs: `The 'readable' event is emitted when there is data available to be read from the stream.` So since in your code there is data at source `news`, the event is getting fired. If you don't provide anything, say `read() { }`, then there's no where to read from, so it's not fired.

Also `The 'readable' event will also be emitted once the end of the stream data has been reached but before the 'end' event is emitted.`

So say you've:

```
const news = null;

if(news) {
  return readable.push(news.shift() + '\n')
}
// this line is pushing 'null' which triggers end of stream
return readable.push(null)
```

Then the `readable` event is fired because it has reached the end of stream but `end` is not fired yet.

You should instead pass `read` option as function as per docs, `read <Function> Implementation for the stream._read() method.`

```
const stream = require('stream')
const readable = new stream.Readable({
    read() {
        if(news.length) {
            return readable.push(news.shift() + '\n')
        }
        return readable.push(null)
    },
    encoding: 'utf8',
    highWaterMark: 16000,
    objectMode: false
})
```

Comment: I'm confused about the words ```The 'readable' event is emitted when there is data available to be read from the stream.```, I thought there is no data at first until you use push() method,  so why "readable" events emitted?